How to get document Config in emEditor plugin (not macro)?
I want to write a emEditor plugin to toggle comment/uncomment, so i need to get LineComment1/LineComment2/CommentBegin/CommentEnd properties from highlightProp of config,
In emeditor macro, it is easy to get config of current file by using document.Config,
how to achieve it in plugin?
thanks!
